# Cached app issue - deployed with capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I have deployed my app for first time. Cap deploy was successful. However I was getting an error on a specific code segment. So I decided to delete this code segment and get the website up and running first before fixing this error.

I run cap deploy again but I am still getting the same error on the code segment that I removed from the source file (I see the error by tailing production.log). It was not suppose to be there. I searched around on the net and found that the problem is that there is a cached version of the app. I found out that a solution would be to delete the cache-copy folder in /shared folder.

I restarted my services (nginx, unicorn) and open the site again and I still get the same error on the code segment I removed.

I checked my new current folder, cached-copy folder and last release folder and all don't have the code segment that produces the error.

It's really odd to me. Any clue whats going on?
Thanks!

Code segment that produces the error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `stripe' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x00000002a85578>):
20:     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
21:     <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
22:     <%= javascript_include_tag "https://js.stripe.com/v1/", type: 'text/javascript' %>
23:     <%= javascript_tag "Stripe.publishableKey = '#{Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key]}';", type: 'text/javascript' %>
24:     <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
25:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
26:     <script type="text/javascript" src="//use.typekit.net/xoh2pss.js"></script>
```

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:23:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__486989174473553269_34754060'

The line 23 was removed but its still shown as generating the error.

Comment: check (nginx, unicorn).log files to get the error

Comment: Can you show that code segment? It might be related to a datastore that's caching.

Comment: @itsnikolay there are no errors in nginx and unicorn files. the error is on production.log and its about loading stripe environment variable but I removed this just to get the website up and running. However I see that an error is produced at the lines I removed and this is odd as the lines are not there.

Comment: @Agis I updated the question above and includes the error

Comment: Are you sure that the unicorns restarted? Also do you have any caching layer above unicorns? Please open a *new tab* in your browser and visit your site again.

Comment: @Agis Yes I am positive that unicorn is restarted. I didn't create any other "caching layers". I tried with a new tab incognito and on another pc. Same issue.

Comment: You can see which is the path that unicorn access and verify that it loads the correct code by opening the relevant file in that very same path.

Comment: @Agis yes I verified that, it relates with the correct conf file and pid

Answer (score 0):

```
# config/initializers/stripe.rb
Stripe::API_KEY = 'asd8df9sadf766'


# application.html.erb
<%= javascript_tag do -%>
  Stripe.publishableKey = <%= Stripe::API_KEY %>;
<% end -%>
```

Comment: thanks. the problem is that even if I add this the app's code will not be updated. I could also just add my Stripe env in the yml file or add my application.yml file that will stop this error.

Comment: did you try to restart server?

Answer (score 0):

Are your assets precompiled and the old all.js (or similar) being redeployed without this change present? If the routine invoked by the javascript portion isn't present that could produce an error -- that might be the stripe method you're trying to invoke.   If they were manually precompiled and you made the change but didn't re-compile it, the redeploy would simply put the old one back out there.